# How to bind 1 port to another one inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker

I pull a container from the main docker registry that runs a service on port 8080. This same port get exposed in the Dockerfile.

I would like to bind the port 80 to the port 8080 inside the container such that if I do that inside the container :

```
curl localhost:80
```

I get the same result as doing that :

```
curl localhost:8080
```

Comment: Docker won't do this for you.  Your options are to run a proxy or launch the service with arguments to tell it to listen on 80 (you can do this with every service I can think of)

Answer (score 0):

one way is to run nginx inside container to listen on port 80 and forward the request to port 8080

Answer (score 0):

On alternative is to use ssh tunneling. To forward requests on localhost:LOCAL_PORT to to REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PORT you would run
`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no REMOTE_SERVER -CNL localhost:LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PORT`

In your case, REMOTE_SERVER would be localhost as well.

```
# Install SSH
service ssh restart
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no localhost -CNL localhost:80:localhost:8080 &
```